# Bootstrap4 CARD Carousel using slick .js

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, carousel, slick.js

I had to create card carousel using slick.js and bootstrap4 . it had to be carousel in responsive view andd no slick in desktop . I am able to implement the slick but bootstrap rows and column doesnt work as accepted.

The slider works but the card column places itself one below the other by overriding bootstrap css . I want it to each card to slide one by one . For ex : slideToShow : 1.5 from right

I had to create card carousel using slick.js and bootstrap4 . it had to be carousel in responsive view andd no slick in desktop . I am able to implement the slick but bootstrap rows and column doesnt work as accepted.

Also i want all the cards to be visible in desktop mode without carousel , which is not working as expected . 
Codepen link is below

PS : Carousel works with cdn link but if we use it through node modules it doesnt work as expected

Requirements are something similar to https://www.fitbit.com/sponsored-events (2nd section in pages)

Comment: https://codepen.io/subhi07/pen/vvgRKx 

Please check code over here

Comment: Please include all question details in the question.  Please do not use comments to add details to your question.  Edit your question, then delete your comments.